# Using new operator without assigning to anyone

Tags: c#

This might be silly question but could anyone explain me what does below statement does:

```
new List<string>() {"1","2"};
```

I am not assigning it to anyone. So writing this statment makes any sense

Comment: You could potentially do something useful with it - `new List<string>() {"1","2"}.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);`

Comment: @GrantWinney I'm going through old piece of code where I found this. So just making sure whether I am missing any concept ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it doesn't make sense. You're correct. You're creating a list, adding items to it, and then forgetting about that list.

In general, it's harder to tell. Some classes have constructors with side effects. You may meaningfully construct such a class, and then not use the created instance, because that side effect was all you were after in the first place. For example, suppose you have a custom `List` class and a helper `ListItem` class. Suppose your `ListItem` has a constructor that takes a `List`, and ensures the list item ends up as part of that list. In that case, you might meaningfully write `new ListItem(list);` without anything else.